# Встака знаков <> в текст element'a из Java DOM

Tags: java, dom

При попытке вызвать setTextContent() со строкой, содержащей < или > в итоговый файл записывается &lt или &rt. Что делать, и как записать эти знаки в содержимое элемента?

Comment: Если вы сделаете это, результирующий документ нарушит стандарт html и не сможет пройти валидацию. Вы уверены, что это именно то, чего вы хотите?

Comment: Да, мне точно нужно вставить эти символы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я уже писал в комментарии, в соответствии со стандартом, символ `<` должен встречаться только в начале тега, а символ `>` в конце, во всех других случаях они должны быть преобразованы в escape-последовательности `&lt;` и `&gt;`. Появление этих символов в неэкранированном виде на месте текстовых узлов сделает документ невалидным и, скорее всего, сломает его отображение в бразуерах. Единственное исключение - это текстовые узлы обёрнутые в секцию [CDATA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```
someNode.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection("<>"));
```

Но, на сколько я понял, такой вариант вас тоже не устроит. Возможно, вас интересует что-то такое:

```
Node disableEscaping = doc.createProcessingInstruction(StreamResult.PI_DISABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING, "<>");
Node enableEscaping = doc.createProcessingInstruction(StreamResult.PI_ENABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING, "<>");

someNode.appendChild(disableEscaping);
someNode.setTextContent("> <");
someNode.appendChild(enableEscaping);
```

Comment: Мне именно CDATA и нужно! Пишу генератор фида для Я.Дзен, а там главный контент и оборачивается этим тегом...

Comment: Тогда я рад, что упомянул его.